# class names after namespace in C++

Tags: c++

New to C++

there is a namespace i.e. and right after it a couple of class names

```
namespace abc {
 class Cursor;
 class BufferAllocator;
....
....
}
```

What does the above class declaration of Cursor and BufferAllocator do here?

Comment: They're forward declarations. They allow you to (e.g.) declare pointers to the classes.

Comment: Declaring that classes, what else can they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cursor` and `BufferAllocator` are simply being forward-declared in their namespace (so they can be used in pointer/reference contexts).

Answer (score 9):

It simply means "these classes exists" in the namespace `abc`, without providing any informations on their implementations.

It's called *forward declarations*.

It can be useful for :

- Avoiding cycles in header inclusions (When class A has a member of class B, and class B has a member of class A)
- Reducing dependencies between classes (because you can have a member pointer to a forward-declared class, but can't have directly a member, as the compiler doesn't know what's the size of the class without its implementation details, but know the size of a pointer). This is used notably in the [Pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

(There might be other uses for this, but these are the most obvious that come to mind).

Answer (score 5):

It's a forward declaration. It tells the following code that "there is a class called Cursor. You don't need to know what's in it [because we're only using it as a pointer or reference in the code, until it has been defined]".

Comment: Additionally, it can also be used in function signatures by value.

Answer (score 0):

It's a forward declaration. It can be used to inform the compiler of the existence of types when you're only going to use a pointer or reference to that type. The size of a pointer or reference is invariant of the type that it refers to, so the compiler doesn't need to see the entire definition of the type in that case; it just needs to know that the type exists first.

This can be useful in cases where the header that normally declares the type is large (think headers that include a lot of declarations or template instantiations), in which case it can decrease your compile times (sometimes significantly). You can just forward-declare the type and skip including the header, so your compiler doesn't need to process it.

Answer (score 0):

namespace are helpful in a way they avoid typing particular classname in  front of every function.

As you are new you will mostly see using namespace std;

so now you can use cout directly if you do not use this statement then you have to write std::cout for every use of cout

hope this helps